# Getting error while running Python code in pandas for pytest

Tags: python, pandas, devops

I'm running a script with import pandas getting the error with stack trace for the code written below importing pandas and os.path to convert CSV to excel.I am also using ExcelWriter which might get deprecated so any alternative solution would be appreciated Kindly help me debug it and let me know where I might be going wrong:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pytest.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    import pandas.testing
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/testing.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas.util.testing import (
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-4.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/testing.py", line 55, in <module>
    slow = pytest.mark.slow
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mark'
```

my code :

```
# This is a sample Python script.

# Press Shift+F10 to execute it or replace it with your code.
# Press Double Shift to search everywhere for classes, files, tool windows, actions, and settings.
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import os.path


def csvToExcelELASummary(src, dest):
    df = pd.read_csv(src)
    li=['Count of MINs Received','Count of MINs for Crediting','Count of MINs not for Crediting',
        'Count of MINs not Processed']
    dict={}
    df_temp=df.copy()
    df_temp=df_temp.groupby(['inner_query.type'])['count'].sum().reset_index()
    for i in li:
        if i in df_temp.values:
            key=df_temp[(df_temp['inner_query.type']==i)].iloc[0]['inner_query.type']
            val=df_temp[(df_temp['inner_query.type']==i)].iloc[0]['count']
            if key in dict.keys():
                dict[key]+=val
            else:
                dict[key]=val
        else:
            dict[i]=0
    print(dict)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(dict.items()))
    df2.rename(columns={0: 'summary_report', 1: 'count'}, inplace=True)

    df3=df.drop(['inner_query.type'],axis=1)
    df3.rename(columns={'inner_query.reason': 'Fallout Reason Breakdown'}, inplace=True)
    df3=df3.dropna()
    print(df2)
    print(df3)
    GFG = pd.ExcelWriter(dest)
    df2.to_excel(GFG,sheet_name='proactive_care_summary_report',header=True, index=False)
    df3.to_excel(GFG,header=True, index=False, startrow=10)
    GFG.save()

def csvToExcelECMSummary(src, dest):

    df = pd.read_csv(src)
    li=['Count of MINs Received','Count of MINs for Broadcast','Count of MINs not for Broadcast',
        'Count of MINs for Adjustment','Count of MINs for Adjustment MSF Rebates',
        'Count of MINs for Adjustment Prepaid Validity','Count of MINs for Adjustment CYA',
        'Count of MINs for Adjustment Goodwill','Count of MINs not Processed']
    dict={}
    df_temp=df.copy()
    df_temp=df_temp.groupby(['inner_query.type'])['count'].sum().reset_index()
    for i in li:
        if i in df_temp.values:
            key=df_temp[(df_temp['inner_query.type']==i)].iloc[0]['inner_query.type']
            val=df_temp[(df_temp['inner_query.type']==i)].iloc[0]['count']
            if key in dict.keys():
                dict[key]+=val
            else:
                dict[key]=val
        else:
            dict[i]=0
    print(dict)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(dict.items()))
    df2.rename(columns={0: 'summary_report', 1: 'count'}, inplace=True)

    df3=df.drop(['inner_query.type'],axis=1)
    df3.rename(columns={'inner_query.reason': 'Fallout Reason Breakdown'}, inplace=True)
    df3=df3.dropna()
    print(df2)
    print(df3)
    GFG = pd.ExcelWriter(dest)
    df2.to_excel(GFG,sheet_name='proactive_care_summary_report',header=True, index=False)
    df3.to_excel(GFG,sheet_name='proactive_care_summary_report',header=True, index=False, startrow=10)
    GFG.save()

def csvToExcel(src, dest):
    # Use a breakpoint in the code line below to debug your script.
    df = pd.read_csv(src)

    GFG = pd.ExcelWriter(dest)
    df.to_excel(GFG,sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

    GFG.save()


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fileList=["ECM_SO_Volume_Notification_Report","ECM_SO_Goodwill_Report",
              "ECM_SO_CYA_Adjustment_Report","ECM_SO_Adjustment_Report",
              "ECM_SO_Summary_Report","ECM_SO_Fallout_MIN_Report",
              "ELA_Credited_Report","ELA_Summary_Report","ELA_Fallout_MIN_Report"]
    srcPath="C:/Users/samratd/OneDrive - AMDOCS/Backup Folders/Documents/"
    destPath="C:/Users/samratd/OneDrive - AMDOCS/Backup Folders/Documents/"
    srcFileList=[]
    destFileList=[]
    todayDate=datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
    print(todayDate)
    for file in fileList:
        srcFileList.append(file+"_"+todayDate+".csv")
        destFileList.append(file+"_"+todayDate+".xls")
    print(srcFileList)
    print(destFileList)
    df=pd.DataFrame()

    for i in range(0,9):
        my_file = srcPath+srcFileList[i]
        if os.path.isfile(my_file):
            if fileList[i]=="ECM_SO_Summary_Report":
                csvToExcelECMSummary(srcPath+srcFileList[i],
                                 destPath+destFileList[i])
            elif fileList[i]=="ELA_Summary_Report":
                csvToExcelELASummary(srcPath+srcFileList[i],
                                 destPath+destFileList[i])
            else:
                csvToExcel(srcPath+srcFileList[i],
                                 destPath+destFileList[i])

        else:
            print(srcPath+srcFileList[i]+" not found! Moving to next..")
            continue


# See PyCharm help at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/
```

running with :

```
python pytst.py
```

Comment: Please, provide a sample of your code where the problem appears. Also, with `import` section

Comment: done..kindly check..